# Combining regular MongoDB query operators with the $or operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to combine a regular MongoDB query operator with an `$or` operator, but I am getting an unexpected result.

Say I have these records:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": null
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "rab",
    "baz": "zab"
  }
]
```

As you see, they share the `foo` value, but diverge in the `bar` and `baz` values.

If I run this query:

```json
{
  "foo": "foo",
  "$or": [
    {
      "bar": "bar",
      "baz": "baz"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get no results. Any ideas why? I expected it to match my first document.

But if I run this query that only includes a single expression inside of the `$or` block:

```json
{
  "foo": "foo",
  "$or": [
    {
      "bar": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I do get a match on the first document. From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) it is stated that an `$or` operator needs two or more expressions. Which means maybe it's just evaluating an `$or` query with a single expression as a normal expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is because of how you're using the expression in your `$or`, you're giving him a single [expression object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expression-objects) and expect him to do `or` logic on that expression, that's not how it works.

What you want to do is just give him multiple expressions, like so:

```
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "$or": [
        {
            "bar": "bar",
        },
        {
            "baz": "baz"
        }
    ]
}
```